# Show sorted elements based on priority

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

can you please help?

I would like to autopopulate column C with values in column B sorted by the priority in column A.

Column A: Project names manually ordered by priority. Most important in top.

Column B: Mixed tasks from multiple projects.

Column C: Expected results.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Szpiep! [take the tour here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Have you seen this [blog post over at Info Inspired on custom order sorting.](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sort-by-custom-order-in-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. We need to strip the `-0` off of the input values, but otherwise its fairly straightforward. If you have FREAK-2 and FREAK-10, this will sort them as 2 and 10 instead of 10 then 2.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFERROR(
   QUERY(
    {B2:B,
     IFERROR(
      REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"(.*)-")&"-"&
      TEXT(
       --REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"-(\d+)"),
       "000")),
     IFERROR(
      VLOOKUP(
      REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"(.*)-")&"*",
       {A2:A,ROW(A2:A)},
       2,FALSE),99)},
   "select Col1
    where
     Col1 is not null and
     Col3 >0
    order by Col3, Col2",0)))
```

[working demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fTYqAlKCO88sGIvEbmc2b88okVvpMtBUGWDf8Djd-MI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: yeah, @daniele, without a match it'll revert to zero via the IFERROR. Did you want these values to go to the bottom of the list or disappear all together? I added a second formula for you to try. It won't return the values without a match.

Comment: try the sheet I linked to at the bottom of the post. With the revised formula, anything without a match will not show up. In the sheet I included a second option that will give all non-matches a priority of 99, so they're at the bottom sorted alphabetically. Not sure why this response is downvoted.

Comment: I think that now it's OK :)

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks you so much! :D

Comment: happy to help! Thanks to Daniele for helping me refine it, too! :)